# documenting shell scripts' parameters

Tags: linux, unix, shell

Is there a convention for documenting shell scripts' parameters?

For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# <description>
#
# Usage:
#  $ ./myScript param1 [param2]
# * param1: <description>
# * param2: <description>
```

A few things I don't like about this particular template:

- the script's file name (`myScript`) appears within the file itself
- parameter description seems weird
- the leading space before `$` is visually useful, but can lead to confusion in languages with block comments, causing some validation tools to complain about mixed/inconsisent indentation (e.g. spaces in this block, tabs for code - provided one prefers tabs, of course)

Are there any guidelines on this?

Comment: `man` pages for formatting and examples of parameter documentation: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6891/how-can-i-add-man-page-entries-for-my-own-power-tools

Answer (score 68):

Traditionally you document your arguments in the usage() function:

```
#!/bin/bash

programname=$0

function usage {
    echo "usage: $programname [-abch] [-f infile] [-o outfile]"
    echo "  -a      turn on feature a"
    echo "  -b      turn on feature b"
    echo "  -c      turn on feature c"
    echo "  -h      display help"
    echo "  -f infile   specify input file infile"
    echo "  -o outfile  specify output file outfile"
    exit 1
}

usage
```

Comment: Thanks to everyone for their responses.
While they are all fairly Bash-specific, they're useful nevertheless.
I'll have to think about how best to implement this (as a common pattern) in Python, Perl, Ruby etc.

Comment: Having thought about this a little more, the in-code documentation is required as well, as it serves a slightly different purpose.
So I will adopt the automated usage info, but would still appreciate some advice on the original issue.

Comment: I have a question. Why should you use exit code 1 here?

Comment: @LRDPRDX Because if you're printing usage, you most likely did not complete the function of the program, so you return failure. A great example is if not supplying any arguments causes the script to call usage, and another script called this script, intending to supply arguments, but not doing so due to a bug, it's ideal for this script to communicate to the calling script that it failed to do anything.

Comment: @DuncanXSimpson What if the arguments-supplier program is intended to print usage at some point? It is probably better to call `exit 1` only in handled unexpected situations rather than in the quite expected situation of asking for help. I would say that printing self usage is part of the function of a program. Also, I'd expect a usage function to just print usage, not to terminate the program, so `exit` should be called outside `usage`.

Comment: How do I call the usage function?

Answer (score 34):

I would recomment using a heredoc:

```
usage () {
    cat <<HELP_USAGE

    $0  [-a] -f <file>

   -a  All the instances.
   -f  File to write all the log lines
HELP_USAGE
}
```

instead of:

```
echo "$0  [-a] -f <file>"
echo
echo "-a  All the instances."
echo "-f  File to write all the log lines."
```

I think it is way cleaner than all these *echo* lines.

Comment: I think this solution is the most beautiful of all the answers. Thanks

Comment: I avoid heredoc only because it destroys indentation.

Answer (score 33):

I usually wrap my usage in function so I can call it from a -h param etc.

```
#!/bin/bash
usage() {
    cat <<EOM
    Usage:
    $(basename $0) Explain options here

EOM
    exit 0
}

[ -z $1 ] && { usage; }
```

Comment: I fixed the here doc for you by indenting the script.  I don't understand the [ -x $1 ] (if the first argument isn't the path to an executable file, produce usage?); the braces and semicolon around the invocation are redundant too.

Comment: Doh, didn't notice the x; changed it to the z it wanted to be.

Comment: I guess the braces are habit so I can include an error message along with the check depending on the check.  Thanks for the indenting code trick!

Comment: You need to quote that `$1` since it could contain spaces and `[` is just a regular program that takes `-z` as the first argument, `]` last. If `$1` contained `"x -o 1 -eq 1"`, it would always show the usage information.

Answer (score 16):

The [Vim bash IDE](http://www.linux.com/feature/114359) that does this:

```
#!/bin/bash
#===============================================================================
#
#          FILE:  test.sh
#
#         USAGE:  ./test.sh
#
#   DESCRIPTION:
#
#       OPTIONS:  ---
#  REQUIREMENTS:  ---
#          BUGS:  ---
#         NOTES:  ---
#        AUTHOR:  Joe Brockmeier, jzb@zonker.net
#       COMPANY:  Dissociated Press
#       VERSION:  1.0
#       CREATED:  05/25/2007 10:31:01 PM MDT
#      REVISION:  ---
#===============================================================================
```

Comment: Ugh, looks like the identification section of COBOL program. *shivers*.

Comment: That looks interesting - will consider that, thanks!
(Though the problem with multi-line comments - as in heredoc - remains.)

Comment: I always use "#:" for this _meta-comments_ so I can separate them from the implementation comments.

Answer (score 7):

I would recommend making your script automatically print usage (if it shouldn't be run without arguments):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [ $# == 0 ]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 param1 [param2]"
    echo "* param1: <description>"
    echo "* param2: <description>"
fi
```

Comment: You can use `$#` as a shortcut for the argument count.

Answer (score 3):

I would rather write:

```
Usage: `basename $0` [option1]|[option2] param1
  Options:
   - option1:  .....
   - option2:  .....
  Parameters:
   - param1:   .....
```

Try to look at the way help is formatted for standard UNIX utilities (ls --help, for instance)

Answer (score 0):

Based on @eddy's [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/687816/2314737) here's the version that takes care of multiple arguments (in this example 2)

```
#!/bin/bash

usage() {
    cat <<EOM
Usage: $(basename $0) <username> <myproject> 
where 
  <username> is your user name
  <myproject> is your project's name
EOM
    exit 1
}

[ $# != 2 ] && { usage; }
for arg in "$@"
do
    [ -z "$arg" ] && { usage; }
done
```

The double check of the length of the array of arguments (`[ $# != 2 ]`) as well as on arguments to be not null (`[ -z "$arg" ]`) is needed to take care of empty strings given as arguments.